# Распределение сообщения по партициям кафки. PHP

Tags: php, apache-kafka

В топике 3 партиции, в 1 уже находится сообщение с нужным ключем, но новое сообщение летит в совершенно другую партицию. Что я делаю не так.

```
$producer = new RdKafka\Producer($conf);

$rd_topic_conf = new RdKafka\TopicConf();

$rd_topic_conf->setPartitioner(RD_KAFKA_MSG_PARTITIONER_CONSISTENT);

$topic = $producer->newTopic($kafkaTopic, $rd_topic_conf);

$mess = [
    "key" => "65558f82601f941c6479936c",
];

$topic->produce(RD_KAFKA_PARTITION_UA, 0, json_encode($mess), '65558f82601f941c6479936c');
```